# DateTime not responding on server change

Tags: php, php-5.3, plesk, centos6

I recently migrated a site from a shared hosting to a Virtual Private Server.
On the shared hosting I had PHP 5.2, and on the VPS I have PHP 5.3.3.
After this migration the DateTime class stopped responding.
the following code used to work fine but now I only get the $test output.

```
$test = $vMonth.'/'.$vDay.'/'.$vYear;
echo $test;
$date = new DateTime($test);
if (!$date) {
    $e = date_get_last_errors();
    foreach ($e['errors'] as $error) {
        echo $error."\n";
    }
    echo "step1";
} else {
    echo $date;
    echo "step2";
}
$vBday = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "Test0";
```

Does anybody know if this is a known issue? or if there is a workaround?
Thank you!

EDIT (php.ini):

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
log_errors = On
display_errors = On
error_log = /tmp/php_errors.log
```

Comment: Check error logs, and make sure you're using `E_ALL` error logging level

Comment: error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

Comment: so what about error logs? If php dies - there is a reason for that

Comment: I configured php.ini to save a log but it has not even been created

Comment: so your question now presumably should be "how to turn on logging in php". It makes no sense to guess

Comment: I configured the ini to save a log and restarted the service, but it was already set by defect to show all errors. Unless there is something that escapes my limited configuration skills, then it should be saved... am I missing something?

Comment: do you see something in your log? If not - then logging doesn't work

Comment: what if you look at `phpinfo()`?

Comment: It only confirms what I have in my config.

Comment: run a tiny file with `<?php $a++;` code. Would you see a notice?

Comment: Next time it wont show you errors, add the following to the top of your php script: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Thank you @alexander7567, I will save that for future reference.

Comment: @alexander7567 I can't begin to thank you enough... life saver! xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
Apparently, a lot of work was done on 5.3 to this class. Mostly to support European+American date style and to add support to more formats. This must have included unexpected changes to the constructor, because it was not recognizing my previous formatting.
The solution was to go for [create from format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
$test = $vYear.'-'.$vMonth.'-'.$vDay;
$date = date_create_from_format("Y-n-j",$test);
$vBday = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that date.timezone is set to a correct value on php.ini. It looks that on some servers (or PHP version?) it is necessary...

Comment: Happy 3rd birthday to the original question! :P